# Load data from file

Tags: c++, file, save, load

I got something like this

```
int main(){
    char N[20];
    int day,month,year,hour,minute,length;
    char group[30],description[100];
    std::cin>>N;
    std::ifstream data(N);
    while(!data.eof()){
    data>>day>>month>>year>>hour>>minute>>length>>group>>description;
    }
return 0;
}
```

and i got data in file in this form

```
23 12 2017 19 25 88 bussiness meeting meeting about new product
```

it's no problem to put integers into variables but i want to put "bussiness meeting" into group and "about new product" into description and the same thing while saving data in file.

Comment: this isn't C but C++

Comment: how are you suppose to delimit the fields if there are no quoting involved?

Comment: To repeat the question:  How do you know it is "business meeting" and "meeting about new product", rather than "business" and "meeting meeting about new product", or "business meeting meeting" and "about new product"?

Comment: Please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Make a lot of your defects go away by using `std::string` for text not character arrays.

Comment: i don't. that's why i want to find solution how can i read and save data

Comment: You may have buffer overflow, because you are not limiting the amount of text read into a variable.

Comment: @bluzazkapturem you CAN'T read the data the way you want, because the file simply doesn't contain enough information to accomplish what you want. The file is badly designed. If the `group` and `description` strings were actually delimited, you would have a fighting chance. But they are not, so you dont

Answer (score 0):

Add `"` before and after `group` and `description` strings. But you need to know that if you going to want to load it, you going to need to parse it somehow. As other people said use `std::string` with C++